# Find the following one-sided limits?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

$$\text{a)} \ \  \lim_{x\to-2^+}(x+3)\frac{|x+2|}{x+2}$$
$$\text{b)} \ \  \lim_{x\to-2^-}(x+3)\frac{|x+2|}{x+2}$$

The answers are:

$$\text{a)} \ \  1$$
$$\text{b)} -1$$

How do you find them? It is certain that if you insert $-2$ in the first problem then you get the limit 1, but that's not true for the second one. How do I find both limits algebraically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets have a look at a). Naturally the troublesome part is $\frac{|x+2|}{x+2}$. Now since we approach -2 from the right we know that $x>-2$. Thus $\frac{|x+2|}{x+2} = \frac{x+2}{x+2} \to 1$ as $x \to -2^+$. Using that the limit of a product is the product of the limits we have that:
$$\lim_{x \to -2^+} (x+3)\frac{|x+2|}{x+2} = 1 \cdot 1 =1$$.

Now try the other using this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$$|x+2| =
\begin{cases}
-(x+2), & \text{if } x<-2 \\
x+2, & \text{if }x \ge -2
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

for a), you can replace the absolute value of the function $f(x)=x+2$ with the function itself, since approaching $-2$ from above means the function inside is positive and we know that $|f(x)|=f(x)$ whenever $f(x)\geq 0$ so
$$
\lim_{x\to-2^+}(x+3)\frac{|x+2|}{x+2}=\lim_{x\to-2^+}(x+3)\frac{x+2}{x+2}=\lim_{x\to-2^+}(x+3)=1
$$
use the same logic for part b.